# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. >

Tags: android

> Could not add entry '0' to cache localJarClasspathSnapshot.bin
>   (D:\Formula.gradle\2.10\tasks_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac\localJarClasspathSnapshot\localJarClasspathSnapshot.bin).
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 23
>     buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
>
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "np.com.deepndra.formulary.formula"
>         minSdkVersion 12
>         targetSdkVersion 23
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
>     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
>     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
>     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.1'
> }
> ```